# Manage documents available in hierarchical folder structure in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am new to DynamoDB (document DB) and need help in designing table structure in 
nosql database.

I need to manage documents which are available in different folders. folder hierarchy can go to nth level and same document can be available in multiple folders.

In case of relational database I can maintain the hierarchy and documents in different tables and extract the required information by applying joins on these tables.

I need to know best way to store this data in DynamoDB tables, so that information can be extracted in most efficient manner. Each user will have certain permission based on which he/ she can view or edit document.

Currently I am trying to store it in following structure:

```
documents = [
{
    _id: ...,
    title: "...",
    date_uploaded: ...,
    folders: [
        folderId,
        ...
    ]
},
...
]

folders = [
{
    _id: ...,
    title: "..."
}
]
```

Here with the help of documentId, I can extract the list of folders in which the document exists and details of that folder from folders table, but an not sure how to maintain the folder hierarchy.

Can someone help me with this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a Many-to-Many relationship here. A Folder can have many Documents and a Document can be in many Folders. There is no one way to model these types of relationships since they tend to be application specific and highly dependent on your access patterns. Since this is the case, I'm going to need to make some assumptions about your application to answer your question. I'll try to make it clear where and about what I'm assuming.

In general with NoSQL, you design your schemas and organize your data to support the specific views found in your application. Many times that involves denormalizing data, particularly in the case of Many-to-Many relationships and is why the strategies for these types of relationships tend to be so application specific.

In the following example, I'm going to assume you have some sort of Master-Detail view where the master lists contain sub-folders and summary information about documents within a particular folder and the detail view displays the all information about the currently selected document.

**Schemas**

---

To start I'm going to define schemas based on the ones you have above but modified slightly to be better suited for DynamoDB.

**Folder**

```
{
  "id": String,
  "parent_id": String,
  "name": String,
}
```

**Document**

```
{
  "id": String,
  "title": String,
  "contents": String,
  "date_modified": String,
  "date_uploaded": String,
}
```

The Document model is pretty self explanatory. Additionally, we are going to create a DocumentSummary which will contain just summary information about a Document.

**DocumentSummary**

```
{
  "id": String,
  "parent_id": String,
  "title": String,
  "date_uploaded": String,
}
```

As a rule of thumb, the DocumentSummary model should be a subset of the Document model and only contain fields that are either immutable, e.g. `date_uploaded`, or mutate very slowly, e.g. `title`. Fields such as `date_modified` might mutate very rapidly which could cause problems (we'll see later why). Also, fields such as `contents` should not go into our summary model. In addition to `contents` being a rapidly muting field, there is nothing "summary" about it. Keep in mind, the closer our summary model is to our full model, the less useful our summary model becomes. At some point we might as well throw away our summary model and only use our full model.

**Tables**

---

We are going to have two tables, DocumentTable and DirectoryTable.

**DocumentTable**

```
Hash Key: "id"
```

The DocumentTable contains our Documents and provides us with the ability to perform CRUD operations by `id`

**DirectoryTable**

```
Hash Key: "parent_id"
Sort Key: "id"
```

The DirectoryTable will contain Folders and DocumentSummaries. Since this table contains two different types, its very important that the IDs for each type cannot collide. I'd suggest prefixing your IDs with a namespace, e.g. "folder-123" and "document-123".

The DirectoryTable gives us the ability to query for all sub-folders and document summaries within a given folder as well as allowing us to update Folders and DocumentSummaries by `parent_id` and `id`.

For example, if we want to find all sub-folders and document summaries within "folder-123" we can Query with the following params.

```
{
    "TableName": "DirectoryTable",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "parent_id = :parent_id",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":parent_id": {"S": "folder-123"},
    }
}
```

*Note:* For top-level folders and documents, you will need to use a dummy `parent_id` such as "root"

In addition, we might want to query for what Folders a particular Document is in. To answer this, we need to create a Global Secondary Index (GSI) on the DirectoryTable

**id-parent_id-index (DirectoryTable GSI)**

```
Hash Key: "id"
Sort Key: "parent_id"
```

Now, we can use Query with the following params to find all parent folder IDs for the document with ID of "document-123".

```
{
    "TableName": "DirectoryTable",
    "IndexName": "id-parent_id-index",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "id = :id",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":id": {"S": "document-123"}
    }
}
```

You might be wondering how do you query for a Folder by `id`. You can simply use the `id-parent_id-index` again with the same Query params as above, substituting "document-123" with the folder ID, e.g. "folder-123". If you have done things correctly, this should produce an array of Items with a length of 1.

Lastly, we need a way to update DocumentSummaries when one of the duplicated fields is updated on the corresponding Document. We can use DynamoDB Streams for this. Create a DynamoDB Stream on the DocumentTable and listen for update events. If the update event indicates that one of the duplicated fields has been modified, use the `id-parent_id-index` to find all of the parent Folders for the Document then update the DocumentSummary by `parent_id` and `id`. This update is potentially very expensive as it is an example of a fan-out problem, e.g. a single Document update causes N DocumentSummary updates. Minimizing this cost is important, particularly at large scales which is why we only want to include immutable or slowly mutating fields in our DocumentSummary.

Comment: Thanks Tom for providing detailed explaination

Comment: Thank you for a brilliant explanation